# Agenda does not display times in front of the log info for todo states that are enclosed in square brackets

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I use doom emacs and it offers `[ ]`, `[-]` and `[X]` as part of the `org-todo-keywords`.

For logging I have updated the default doom keywords to include the logging specification using `!/@` f.e.

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO(t)" "PROJ(p/!)" "LOOP(r@/!)" "STRT(s/!)" "WAIT(w@/!)" "HOLD(h@/!)" "IDEA(i/!)" "|" "DONE(d!/@)" "KILL(k@/@)")
        (sequence "[ ](T)" "[-](S/!)" "[?](W@/!)" "|" "[X](D!/@)")
        (sequence "|" "OKAY(o)" "YES(y)" "NO(n)")))
```

In the org-agenda I noticed that the state changes for these states are not listed with the corresponding time when `org-agenda-log-mode` is active with the following settings:

```
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
(setq org-agenda-log-mode-items '(closed clock state))
(setq org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed clock state))
(setq org-log-reschedule 'time)
(setq org-log-refile 'time)
(setq org-log-redeadline 'note)
```

Here is an example to display what it looks like instead:

```
Tuesday    25 October 2022
  inbox:      10:00 ┄┄┄┄┄ State:     (DONE) DONE Test1 TODO -> DONE
  inbox:      State:     ([X]) [X] Test2 [ ] -> [X]
```

The headline with Test2 is displayed without the time. Both headlines have a LOGBOOK drawer that does look the same. Note that the date of the LOGBOOK entry must perhaps be adjusted to appear in your agenda.

```
* DONE Test1 TODO -> DONE
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2022-10-25 Tue 10:00]
:END:

* [X] Test2 [ ] -> [X]
:LOGBOOK:
- State "[X]"        from "[ ]"        [2022-10-25 Tue 10:00]
:END:
```

Further it seems like all todo keywords that start with [ and end with ] like f.e. `[~~~]` are not displayed with the corresponding time but below the time-grid with `State:` in front like seen above.

I believe I tracked down the function that generates the `State:` entries (https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9bfe00dda6b59d9b93eb7a825f6e0868afa1cca3/lisp/org/org-agenda.el#L5943) but I am not really able to understand the function and what is causing this behavior as I am fairly new to emacs/elisp

Is there someway to show the tasks with the checkbox style todo keywords with time?

Is this a bug or a feature that I can configure?

Comment: That looks wrong: these are checkbox states for list items, not TODO states for headlines.

Comment: I have org-todo-keywords to include them as states - in fact these are the default org-todo-keywords for doom emacs (minus the @/! stuff for logging). And as mentioned above todo keywords like [~~] will also be displayed in the different fashion.

I updated the question to include this information

Comment: OK - you are right, it seems to work(for some version of "work")  even though it looks strange to my eyes.

Comment: I currently believe that the linked code in org-agenda has problems recognizing the date if there are other pairs of square brackets in the entry.
Are you able to reproduce this behavior by using the provided org-todo-keywords and inserting the headings into an org-agenda file?

Comment: No - even if I change the timestamps in the logbook (BTW, you are missing colons after both `:END`s - run `M-x org-lint` to catch these things) to today's date, I get an empty agenda. Only when I add e.g. a `SCHEDULED` timestamp do I get an agenda and it looks fine: `foo31:      23:20...... Scheduled:  [X] Test2 [ ] -> [X]`. I'm on Emacs 29.0.50 (built back in June, so not quite up-to-date) and Org mode version 9.5.3 (release_9.5.3-6-gef41f3 @ /usr/local/share/emacs/29.0.50/lisp/org/), the version of Org mode distributed with the version of Emacs at that time.

Comment: BTW, I don't know if Doom does this by default, but I had to `(setq org-log-into-drawer t)` as well as setting `org-todo-keywords`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip with org-lint. I did not mention that it requires to have `org-agenda-log-mode-items` set to `(closed clock state)` for the state changes to appear in the agenda. Then the state changes should appear in the agenda.
I will update the question again to include all my related settings and fix the drawers.